# PhpMyAdmin dá erro 404 no Linux

Tags: linux

Segui a instalação conforme [esse link](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/phpMyAdmin-no-Linux-MInt-e-Ubuntu), porém quando digito http://localhost/phpmyadmin, dá erro 404. Parece que instalou corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisa de alguma permissão ou algo assim? Reiniciei o Apache e nada.

Comment: Como está o arquivo my.conf(ou o equivalente ao arquivo de configuração)?

Comment: Olá Articuno. Confesso que sou novo no Linux. Como eu faria para ver esse arquivo? Vi que o PhpMyAdmin está dentro da pasta /usr/share/. No Windows ele costumava ficar dentro da pasta www. Seria esse o erro?

Comment: Acredito que seja o arquivo config.db.php conforme está no print. EDIT: `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Comment: Tive que dar permissão no arquivo e aparece as informações $dbuser='phpmyadmin';
$dbpass='111488';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';

Comment: Não sei se seria o modo correto, mas copiei a pasta e coloquei dentro da pasta /var/ww/html e funcionou.

Comment: Reiniciou o serviço do apache? Talvez isso tenha resolvido, todos os tutoriais que li aqui mandam fazer isso após instalar o phpmyadmin

Comment: Reiniciei, mas não havia funcionado, mas funcionou depois que copiei a pasta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Enfrentei a mesma dificuldade e consegui resolver o problema apenas incluindo a linha `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` no final do arquivo `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

**Fonte:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJjEeIFdoxg

Answer (score 0):

Você é obrigado a digitar a URL no navegador em minúsculas `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`. Se digitar em maiúsculas `/PhpMyAdmin` a aplicação não será achada, porque assim está definido na configuração do servidor Apache:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
```

Funcionou depois que você copiou os arquivos porque você criou o diretório e fez um instalação "nova" de aplicação dentro do diretório **www** do servidor, sem, na verdade, utilizar a que já existe instalada por default.

Comment: Só corrigindo, obrigado a digitar em minusculas não existe a possibilidade de case sensitive nas urls do browser tambem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366229/case-sensitive-urls-in-apache

Comment: Na verdade coloquei na url em caixa baixa. Aqui coloquei PhpMyAdmin de forma figurativa, é o vício de colocar caixa alta nas primeiras palavras, mas obrigado por me atentar a esse detalhe. Ficarei mais atento da próxima vez. Outro ponto é que instalei o PHP, Apache e Mysql separadamente. Não estou  usando o Xampp.

Comment: Entendo, grato pela observação.